# Java Jar compiled but can't execute

Tags: java

So I have file `Test.java` with simple main class code.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("123");
  }
}
```

and `MANIFEST.MF` file with:

```
Main-Class: Test
```

Then in CMD I type:

```
javac -verbose Test.java
```

then

```
jar cmf MANIFEST.MF Test.jar Test.class Test.java
```

then

```
java -jar Test.jar
```

with output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
```

Comment: Add a new line after `Main-Class` in the `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: Now it prints other error.

Comment: Works here. No other changes. What other error?

Comment: I edited post with new error.

Comment: Delete the jar file. Run the `javac` and `jar` commands again. Exactly as here. Because I did. And it works here. Can't help you beyond that.

Comment: Still not working, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your original error, which was caused by not having a newline after the `Main-Class` declaration in the manifest. The following is a complete shell log of the commands and files used:

```
bash-5.0$ ls
MANIFEST.MF Test.java
bash-5.0$ cat MANIFEST.MF
Main-Class: Test

bash-5.0$ cat Test.java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("123");
  }
}
bash-5.0$ javac Test.java
bash-5.0$ jar cmf MANIFEST.MF Test.jar Test.class Test.java
bash-5.0$ java -jar Test.jar
123
bash-5.0$
```

Comment: And I'm getting same error doing the same thing as you, weird.